# onblur not returning the most updated value

Tags: php, html

Please excuse my ignorance. I want to always retain the current value (that I have supplied by changing the default value) in the input box when I click outside the text box. But the following code returns to the default value if after modification I again click the text box and then click outside the text box. But I want to retain the most updated value always in the textbox.

Perhaps I have to make changes in the area `this.value=' <?php echo "$r1[MAJORS1]" ?>';`, but not understanding how to do that.

Any help please

```
onfocus="if(this.value!=''){ this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}"
onblur="if(this.value==''){ this.value='<?php echo "$r1[MAJORS1]"?>';   this.style.color='#000';}"
```

Comment: `<?php echo "$r1[MAJORS1]"?>` runs on the server side in your PHP script, and generates JavaScript that has a fixed value in it. You will need to create a separate JavaScript variable, write the current value into it in the `onfocus` function, and then assign that into `this.value` in your onblur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

```
<input type="text"
data-value="<?php echo htmlentities("$r1[MAJORS1]"); ?>"
placeholder="<?php echo htmlentities("$r1[MAJORS1]"); ?>"
onfocus="if(this.value!=''){
  this.value='';
  this.style.color='#000';
  this.setAttribute('placeholder',this.getAttribute('data-value'));
}"
onblur="if(this.value==''){
  this.value=this.getAttribute('data-value');
  this.style.color='#000';
}else{
  this.setAttribute('data-value',this.value);
}"
value="<?php echo htmlentities("$r1[MAJORS1]"); ?>">
```

Not exactly pretty though. Messing with the default functionality of the user's browser has a tendency to confuse. I believe my placeholder usage, though, will make it less confusing for the user that their input will revert to whatever the placeholder reads.

See my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lvs77bv/

I don't, however, know if `MAJORS1` is supposed to be a constant or a key in your `$r1` array, though. If it's a key, make sure to quote it to prevent warnings otherwise PHP will think it's a constant. But PHP will fallback, in any case, if the constant isn't defined and treat it as a key in the array, although will generate warnings.

**Edit:**
If you'd like to allow for blank values, you could either add a button to clear the field like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Lvs77bv/1/

Or, as I'd suggest, simply get rid of all the clutter you're trying to code, which affect the user's default browser functionally, and simply use `this.select()` instead when the field is focused:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Lvs77bv/2/

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: One disadvantage of this method is that we can not leave a input box blank. How to overcome it?

Comment: That's what you wanted to overcome, no? Maybe put a "clear" button next to it that when clicked clears the field and its history.